# How to add a line break in python?

Tags: python, line-breaks

I just made a program in python but the statements are too close to each other in the output. So how can i add a line break between two statements in python.

Comment: Do you mean a line break in your script, or a line break in your output?

Comment: You can simply do a `print` or `print()` on its own to give you a blank line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can print new line characters:

```
print('\n'*numlines)
```

Answer (score 6):

`\n` gives you a new line. You can put it anywhere in a string and when printing it you get a new line.

```
In [1]: print('ab')
ab

In [2]: print('a\nb')
a
b
```

There are more of this kind, including tabs etc. 
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals

Answer (score 3):

```
print(output1 + "\n")
print(output2)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print a list of statements with line break:

```
    list=['statement one','statement two', 'statement three']
    list_element_on_separate_line = '\n'.join(list)
    print(list_element_on_separate_line)`
>>>
statement one
statement two
statement three
```