# Add new line to string using for loop

Tags: python

I want to add a new line in a string and then write something in that new line.
I did it like that:

```
for mp3file in mp3gen():
 songsList = songsList + "/n" + mp3file #create new line and add song name
print(songsList)
```

but the resulting string is like that:

```
/n./sdpita.mp3/n./swoosh.mp3/n./cox.mp3
```

Comment: The newline character is ```\n```, not `/n`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a line break in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377903/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `'/n'` with `'\n'`. Note that, `/` is just a forward slash. The backward slash, `\` is the escape character.

```py
print('line-1' + '\n' + 'line-2')
```

**Output**:

```
line-1
line-2
```

Comment: i found it like that "/n" on a website

Answer (score 1):

The symbol for newline is '\n'.

Use this code:

```
for mp3file in mp3gen():
    songsList = songsList + '\n' + mp3file #create new line and add song name
print(songsList)
```

Comment: That’s just the same code with the same mistake.

Comment: I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

reason for your output is that : `/n` is just like any other string .

new line can be achieved using the `os` module as follows :

```
import os
name = 'line1'+ os.linesep + 'line2'
print(name)
```

Output:

```
line1
line2
```

or You can Use the escape Character `\n` which will give you the same result .